# Take user id from php for change password

Tags: javascript, php, session, passwords

I have this code for change password on the personal page of the user on my website. The script working but the problem is that work's only on id "60". how I can take the id from the page and set in this code? my page is like this "www.example.com/area-personale.php?**id=60**". and why the script start immediately when I enter on the page and i prefer that it starts when I press on submit.

```js
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="frmChange" method="post" action=""
        onSubmit="return validatePassword()">
        <div style="width: 500px;">
            <div class="message"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"
                width="500" align="center" class="tblSaveForm">
                <tr class="tableheader">
                    <td colspan="2">Change Password</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="40%"><label>Current Password</label></td>
                    <td width="60%"><input type="password"
                        name="currentPassword" class="txtField" /><span
                        id="currentPassword" class="required"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label>New Password</label></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="newPassword"
                        class="txtField" /><span id="newPassword"
                        class="required"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <td><label>Confirm Password</label></td>
                <td><input type="password" name="confirmPassword"
                    class="txtField" /><span id="confirmPassword"
                    class="required"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit"
                        value="Submit" class="btnSubmit"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
  <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["id_user"] = "60";
$conn = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x") or die("Connection Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
?>

<?php
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT password FROM vm_users WHERE id_user='" . $_SESSION["id_user"] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if ($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE  vm_users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE id_user='" . $_SESSION["id_user"] . "'");
        $message = "Password modificata";
    } else
        $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Change Password</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
<script>
function validatePassword() {
var currentPassword,newPassword,confirmPassword,output = true;

currentPassword = document.frmChange.currentPassword;
newPassword = document.frmChange.newPassword;
confirmPassword = document.frmChange.confirmPassword;

if(!currentPassword.value) {
 currentPassword.focus();
 document.getElementById("currentPassword").innerHTML = "required";
 output = false;
}
else if(!newPassword.value) {
 newPassword.focus();
 document.getElementById("newPassword").innerHTML = "required";
 output = false;
}
else if(!confirmPassword.value) {
 confirmPassword.focus();
 document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "required";
 output = false;
}
if(newPassword.value != confirmPassword.value) {
 newPassword.value="";
 confirmPassword.value="";
 newPassword.focus();
 document.getElementById("confirmPassword").innerHTML = "not same";
 output = false;
}  
return output;
}
```

Comment: Url params can be found in the `$_GET` variable.

Comment: why did you hard code the value 60 here  $_SESSION["id_user"] = "60"; ? Instead pick it from $_GET variable like this $_SESSION["id_user"] = $_GET["id"]

Comment: How and where is the users id initially set?

Answer (score 0):

I used this and now works! 
$_SESSION["id_user"] = $_GET["id"]